# How to use fetch inside another fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have this class which is supposed to authenticate a user (in this case a moderator)

```
import Cookie from "universal-cookie";
import { promiseNotification, updateNotification } from "./addNotification";

const cookies = new Cookie();

class Authentication {
    token;
    role;

    login = (username, password) => {
        const id = promiseNotification("Login...")

        fetch("auth/get-token", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            updateNotification(id, data);
            if (data.token) {
                cookies.set("token", data.token);
                this.setToken();
                return this.setRole(); //If I understand correctly this returns a promise
            }
        }).then(() => window.location.replace("/mod")) //and this handles the setRole promise
        .catch((error) => {alert("Error occurred login in"); console.log(error)});
    }

    setRole = async () => {
        return fetch(`/auth/get-role/${this.token}`, {method: 'GET'}).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.role = data.role);
    }

    setToken = () => {
        this.token = cookies.get("token") || "";
    }
}

export default new Authentication();
```

When I call the login function the role and token should be set in the class instance and after it finishes it should redirect the user to the mods page. In the mods page I have this logic to prevent non moderators from accessing it.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(auth)); //This prints an empty object, meaning that none of the actions that happened in login had any effect

        if (!["administrator", "moderator"].includes(auth.role)) {
            createNotification("You are not a moderator", "error");
            history.push("/admin-login");
        }
    }, []);
```

Why aren't any of the properties in the auth object being update?

Comment: just glancing here, isn't the issue that you're reloading the page with `window.location.replace`? that would clear out your auth object

Comment: @Liam You're right, that might be the issue but I can't use react-router's history since auth isn't a react component. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: well you could 1) move your auth logic into a hook, `useAuth` for example (which would return the auth functions). that would allow you to use react-router hooks within it. 2) you could pass react router's `push` as a callback into `login`, assuming you are calling `login` from inside a component. the other alternative is to use a different routing solution like Next's router which can be used outside of components.